# python regex weirdness

Tags: python, regex

I thought I was ok with regex - but this has me confused - I have this line in python:

```py
dependencies = re.findall( r"-- *depends *on *([^ ]*.*[^ ]) *$", script, re.MULTILINE)
```

which works really well with:

```
"-- depends on    b    "    -> ["b"]
"-- depends on b"           -> ["b"]
"--dependson  green things    \n-- depends on red things\nother stuff"" -> ["green things", "red things"]
"-- depends on b \n-- depends on c" -> ["b", "c"]
```

but doesn't work on

```
"-- depends on b\n-- depends on c" -> ["b\n-- depends on c"]
```

I get that it's going to be some weirdness about the fact that $ matches before the newline - but what I don't get is how to fix the regex?

Comment: Results look weird if the specs are not set precisely. What are your pattern requirements? Did you mean to match any chunk of chars other than whitespace at the end of line after `depends on`? Then try `-- *depends *on *(\S+) *$`. Or, even `--[^\S\r\n]*depends[^\S\r\n]*on[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)[^\S\r\n]*$` to support Unicode horizontal whitespace.

Comment: no - I want to match exactly as the results show - the dependency can quite happily have spaces in it....   so "-- depends on   purple people eaters     " should return "purple people eaters" - but of course throw way any whitespace at the beginning and end of the expression

Comment: Then it must be something like `-- *depends *on *(\S(?:.*\S)?) *$`, or even ``-- *depends *on *(.*\S) *$``

Comment: although going off what you suggest - this works: 

r"--[^\S\r\n]*depends[^\S\r\n]*on[^\S\r\n]+([^\s\r\n]*[^\r\n]*\S)\s*$"

but it's as ugly as - unicode aside, I still don't understand why original one didn't

Comment: It is evident: `[^ ]` matches any char other than a space, so it matches a newline char.

Comment: oh.  I thought that was that was the entire point of re.multiline - to prevent that.   learn something new every day. - thank you!

Comment: `re.M` only makes `$` match end of any line, not just the end of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `re`, [`re.MULTILINE` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M) only redefines the behavior of two anchors, `^` and `$`, that start matching start and end of any *line*, not just *the whole string*:

> When specified, the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character '$' matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each newline). By default, '^' matches only at the beginning of the string, and '$' only at the end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string. Corresponds to the inline flag `(?m)`.

Next, the `[^ ]` negated character class matches *any char other than a literal regular space char* (`\x20`, dec. code 32). Thus, `[^ ]*` matches any zero or more chars other than a space (including a newline, too).

You can use

```py
-- *depends *on *(.*\S) *$
```

Or, if you can have non-breaking spaces or other horizontal Unicode spaces

```py
--[^\S\r\n]*depends[^\S\r\n]*on[^\S\r\n]*(.*\S)[^\S\r\n]*$
```

In Python, you can use

```py
h = r'[^\S\r\n]'
pattern = fr'--{h}*depends{h}*on{h}*(.*\S){h}*$'
```

The `{h}*(.*\S)` part does the job: zero or more spaces are matched and consumed first, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (`.*`) + a non-whitespace char (`\S`) are captured into Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's matching the "\n" newline as "not a space" you can fix it like so for this example:

`-- *depends *on *([^ \n]*.*[^ \n]) *$`

You probably really wanted something like:

`--\s*depends\s*on\s*(\S*.*\S)\s*$`

`\s` means "any space type" and `\S` means any NOT space type.